# EXCEPTION: Error in ./e class e_Host - inline template 0:0

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

While upgrading an `angular2` project to RC5 I ran into a big problem. Reduced all code to the minimum to debug the issue but did not find it's root. Every request of my app results in the following error mesage (Developer console in browser):

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./e class e_Host - inline template 0:0
>   ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: The selector "ng-component" did not match any elements

My streamlined code looks like this, I believe this is as basic as one can get:

**main.ts**

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts"/>
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AdminModule }              from './component/admin/admin.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AdminModule);
```

**admin.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule}         from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule}                from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {TestComponent} from '../admin/test/test';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [TestComponent],
    providers: [],
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    bootstrap: [TestComponent],
})
export class AdminModule {
}
```

**test.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    //templateUrl  : 'public/component/admin/test/test.html',
    template: '<h1>Hello World!</h1>',
    directives: []
})
export class TestComponent {}
```

I double and triple checked each path and include for it's validity and everything is fine so far.

My `npm` setup is like this:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Angular2Boilerplate",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Angular2Boilerplate",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "angular2-localstorage": "^0.3.0",

    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "primeng": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "primeui": "^4.1.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.10.0",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-debug": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-inject": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-rimraf": "^0.1.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp-sass-glob-import": "^0.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.1",
    "gulp-tslint": "^1.4.4",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.5.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.1",
    "superstatic": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "angular2",
    "typescript",
    "sass",
    "gulp"
  ],
  "author": "André Kirchner",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Tried everything I could imagine to trace down the problem but now I need your help. Does Anyone have an idea what's goig so terribly wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `selector` field in your `TestComponent` and you need to use that component in your `index.html` because it is the one you are bootstraping. I just tested it in my project, when I remove `<my-app>Loading...</my-app>` from `index.html`, I get exactly the same error:

[image: <code>EXCEPTION: The selector "my-app" did not match any elements</code>]

Comment: Missed the most stupid thing when I reduced the code for debugging :-( There are still other errors but thanks so far.

Comment: Don't worry, it happens to everyone. :) Feel free to post here if you encounter more problems.